# Ionic 2 Included Database

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have been looking into how to use the included SQLStorage plugin to create local persistent storage. My goal is to create such a database, but include it in the app files such that the data will not need to be re-retrieved. I know that when setting up a database there is an existingDatabase flag, but this does not seem to have the intended behavior. Is there a way to specify the database's location to the www folder, or something to that effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the db copy plugin available here: https://github.com/an-rahulpandey/cordova-plugin-dbcopy

Your `.db` should be in `www` dir, and if it has already been copied again.

```
window.plugins.sqlDB.copy("my.db", function() {
    db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("my.db"); //replace with your db name
}, function(error) {
    console.error("There was an error copying the database: " + error);
    db = $cordovaSQLite.openDB("my.db"); 
});
```

You'll need to adapt the above code for use with ionic2's sql storage.

Comment: Do you know of a way to delete the copy of the DB in the "www" folder since this will be wasted space once loaded into the app directory?

Comment: @djrpascu that is not possible as the application directory is read only. It is accessible at `cordova.file.applicationDirectory`. If you're worried about wasted space, you should download data on run time to seed the db.